# How to traverse examples in tf.data.Dataset backward?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Usually when using tensorflow dataset api, assuming there is not shuffling, tensorflow will retrieve the first serialized example of the `tfrecords`, and then proceeds sequentially to retrieve the remaining examples. Therefore, is there a way to start from the last example, and then proceed backwards?

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: I assume you are looking for something more flexible than this.                                                                   `data = tf.constant([0,1,2,3])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.reverse(data,[0]))
next = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

for i in range(4) :
    print(sess.run([next]))`

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward way to do this right now. The thing is `tf.data` is designed to work sequentially in order to be able to handle very large datasets, and traversing a dataset backwards, in general, would require going to the end first, saving in memory what you have seen, and then iterate from the end... this would defeat the point for large datasets, and actually be impossible when using `repeat`... Would you have the option to save the tfrecord files again in reverse order?

Answer (score 0):

This is, unfortunately, not an ideal solution, but this is what I've been using:

```
def reverse(ds: tf.Data.dataset) -> tf.Data.dataset:
    def reduce_fn(state, x):
      return tf.concat([x[::-1], state], axis=0)
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(ds.batch(256, drop_remainder=False).reduce(tf.zeros((0,), tf.float32), reduce_fn))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**